# How do I clone a conda environment from one python release to another?

Tags: python, conda

I have a python 2.7 conda environment and would like to create an equivalent environment with python 3.4.  I am aware of the `--clone` option when creating environments, but it won't accept additional arguments, like `python=3.4`.  Is there a way to do this automatically?  I thought about trying to use the output from `conda list --export`, but that also encodes the python release.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

One way would be to

```
conda list --export > exported-packages.txt
```

And then edit that file to remove the last part of each package with the `py27_0` parts (you might also want to remove the versions, in case some version of a package doesn't have a Python 3 version).  Then

```
conda create -n py3clone --file exported-packages.txt
```

Another idea would be to clone the environment:

```
conda create -n clonedenv --clone oldenv
conda install -n clonedenv python=3.4
conda update -n clonedenv --all
```

Note that obviously both of these will fail if you have some package that doesn't have a Python 3 version.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, when I tried

```
conda create -n <env-name> exported-packages.txt
```

It gave me an error saying Could not parse name of env in the yml fie.

What worked for me was

```
conda env create --name <env-name> exported-packages.txt
```

Ref: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6827

Answer (score -3):

I tried this and had a lot of issues with plot.ly being updated to v. 4. My code was written on 3.10 and didn't feel like changing it. I had to copy the whole environment (every single file from \envs) from one machine to next, it works.

Comment: This is not an answer.