# conda can't clone an environment when creating an ipykernel

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

I'd like to avoid installing every individual package in a new environment with the following command in anaconda3:

```
conda create -n py3 ipykernel --clone root
```

but I get this error:

```
TooManyArgumentsError: Too many arguments: did not expect any arguments for --clone. Got 1 argument (ipykernel) and expected 0.
```

First cloning the environment and then installing ipykernel also doesn't work:

```
~>conda create -n py3 --clone root
[...]
~>source activate py3
(py3) ~>conda install ipykernel
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ..........


InstallError: Install error: Error: one or more of the packages already installed depend on 'conda'
and should only be installed in the root environment: conda-env
These packages need to be removed before conda can proceed.
```

My end goal is to have a couple envs I can launch in jupyter notebook. I'd like to avoid having to reinstall every package for every env in the case that the python version is the same as [root] env. Having just downloaded the full anaconda distribution, I find myself rebuilding it piecemeal into the environment.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: clone is going to be an exact clone, so you won't be able to use it for 2.7 vs. 3.5

Comment: You may be able to use the following method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664072/how-do-i-clone-a-conda-environment-from-one-python-release-to-another

Comment: I've confused the matter by discussing other python versions (2.7).  My question is that I don't know how to create an ipykernel env that is the same as root without having to recreate [root] from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Conda itself can only be installed in root. Just follow the instructions. 
Inside your new environment, uninstall `conda-env`:

```
(py3) ~> conda unistall conda-env
```

Now, try to install again:

```
(py3) ~>conda install ipykernel
```