# Installed Python 3.6 using 'Conda install', unable to run old 2.7 python programs

Tags: python, anaconda

I have Anaconda 2.7 python installed on my mac book, I wanted to try Python 3.6, so installed the package .. tried the following, Python 3.6 seems to be installed now, but Im unable to run my old 2.7 python scripts.

Kindly help me in restoring my Python environment, I want 2.7, 3.6 version to co-exists, I should be able to switch easily between these 2 versions.

```
$ conda create --name python3.6 python=3.6 
$ source activate python3.6 
$ unset PYTHONPATH 
$ python pyplot2.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pyplot2.py", 
line 2, in <module>
import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `ModuleNotFoundError` tells you, there is no module named 'pandas' installed. So you have to install it first. You can see all your installed packages with `conda list`. You shouldn't see it there. To install it just enter `conda install pandas` and it should work.

If you would like to have all the packages in your Python 3.6 version, that you also had in your 2.7 version you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664072/how-do-i-clone-a-conda-environment-from-one-python-release-to-another)

Comment: Thanks. Installed the pandas module with 'conda install pandas' command.This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely have both python 2 and 3 working in separate envs.

As Leon points out you needed to install additional libraries. More generally, when you create a new env it will be a fresh install, free of almost any libraries. You will need to install your libs with `conda install lib` or `conda update lib`.

If you had a lot of libs, another alternative would be to clone your working env into a new one and then update python in the new one:

```
conda create -n python3.6 --clone base
conda update python=3.6
```

To switch between envs, use `activate [env name]` and then `deactivate` to get back to `base` env. To see all your envs: `conda env list`.