# How to create an python evironment, where only difference is version of python, in conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I currently have a python 3.7 installed by using anaconda on the machine. My intention is to create a lower version of python environment, say 3.6, for reason of compatibility. I follow the documentation to create the conda environment as `conda create -n py36 python=3.6` However, this environment is a clean version of python, where many additional package like numpy, scipy are missing and these packages are already installed on python3.7. So what is the best way that I can create not only a python but also migrate all other packages in previous python version.(python3.7)

I understand the dependency may be different since some packages are not compatible with old version of python, but I still want to migrate as many packages as possible and let conda itself to decide the dependency tree. Current, what I can do is to first create a clean environment and manually `conda install numpy` and so on, which definitely not a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a conda environment from one python release to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664072/how-do-i-clone-a-conda-environment-from-one-python-release-to-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Save all the info about previous env in requirements file
conda list -e > requirement.txt
```

then change the python version in the created 'requirement.txt' file

```
#the create new env from requirement file:
conda env create -f requirement.txt
```

Comment: I think the last line should be `conda env create -f requirement.txt`

Comment: The easier route is to clone, a la https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664072/how-do-i-clone-a-conda-environment-from-one-python-release-to-another